# count(*) based on the gender condition

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have the following table in oracle10g.

```
   state     gender   avg_sal   status
    NC           M      5200     Single 
    OH           F      3800     Married
    AR           M      8800     Married
    AR           F      6200     Single
    TN           M      4200     Single
    NC           F      4500     Single
```

I am trying to form the following report based on some condition. The report should look like the one below. I tried the below query but count(*) is not working as expected

```
state     gender no.of males no.of females   avg_sal_men      avg_sal_women
 NC           M       10            0           5200                 0
 OH           F        0            5           0                  3800
 AR           M        16           0           8800                  0
 AR           F        0            12          0                  6200
 TN           M        22            0          4200                  0
 NC           F        0             8          0                   4500
```

I tried the following query but I am not able to count based onthe no.of males and no.of females..

```
    select State, "NO_OF MALES", "$AVG_sal", "NO_OF_FEMALES", "$AVG_SAL_FEMALE"
    from(
    select State,
    to_char(SUM((CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN average_price ELSE 0 END)),'$999,999,999') as "$Avg_sal_men,
     to_char(SUM((CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN average_price ELSE 0 END)), '$999,999,999') as "$Avg_sal_women,
     (select count (*) from table where gender='M')"NO_OF MALES",
    (select count (*) from table where gender='F')"NO_OF_FEMALES"
     from table group by State order by state);
```

Comment: What are the requirements for aggregating the "avg_sal" figures? I don't think you have the "avg_sal_men" and "avg_sal_women" logic right. Is this supposed to be the Sum total of the "avg_sal" column, which I presume is the Average Salary of people with the given characteristics in the given state? If so, taking a Sum across these numbers doesn't make any sense. Mind you, taking an Average across these numbers also won't make sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` as an expression (which you already know...). And the subquery is unnecessary.

```
select State
     , sum(case gender when 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as "no.of males"
     , sum(case gender when 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as "no.of females"
     , to_char(
           SUM(
               (
                   CASE
                   WHEN gender = 'M' THEN average_price
                   ELSE 0
                   END
               )
           )
         , '$999,999,999'
       ) as "Avg_sal_men",
       to_char(SUM((CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN average_price ELSE 0 END))
              ,'$999,999,999'
     ) as "Avg_sal_women"
from table
group by State;
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not actually know Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You are Conting by this sub-query `select count (*) from table where gender='M'` which always count the total number of male in your whole table....and you are doing same for counting  female... 
So you Can Try like this...

```
select State, "NO_OF MALES", "$AVG_sal", "NO_OF_FEMALES", "$AVG_SAL_FEMALE"
        from(
        select State,
        to_char(SUM((CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN average_price ELSE 0 END)),'$999,999,999') as "$Avg_sal_men",
         to_char(SUM((CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN average_price ELSE 0 END)), '$999,999,999') as "$Avg_sal_women,
        Sum(Case when gender='M' then 1 else 0 end) "NO_OF MALES",
         Sum(Case when gender='F' then 1 else 0 end) "NO_OF_FEMALES"
         from table group by State order by state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
select state
      ,sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end)      as nof_males
      ,sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end)      as nof_females
      ,avg(case when gender = 'M' then average_price end) as avg_sal_male
      ,avg(case when gender = 'F' then average_price end) as avg_sal_female
  from table
 group 
    by state;
```

..add formatting as required.